# TeX Live Utility (unable to find update server)

Tags: texlive, updating

I know this is a duplicate, but the other question are already pretty old...

When I start Tex Live Utility. It says that 
http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
is not available.

When you copy the address in the browser, it says the same. Does anyone knows another server?

ON hold.
Ok, no problems if this question will be deleted... but the problem persists. I don't want to polute the forum, but this is the only forum I know for LateX...

Comment: The core DANTE CTAN server seems to be down at the moment: the mirror system of course relies on this server being available. This will be a passing issue: I'm afraid 'wait for it to be fixed' is the best we can say.

Comment: Indeed, just after writing that comment the server came back up (I have an `ssh` login to it for other reasons, so can test even if http is not working!)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a non reproducible problem (server was momentarily down)

Comment: @arne If you still can't access the system then something is presumably up at 'your end': apart from the odd passing outage the mirror system is reliable (up for me at present, for example).

Comment: ok, I will try a reïnstall on my side. Thanks for the thinking.

Comment: reïnstalling MacTeX.pkg did the job...