# Live TeX Utility 'Unable to find a valid update server' error message

Tags: errors, mac, tex-live-utility

When I open the TeX Live Utility (version 1.34), the following message appears: `Unable to find a valid update server`.

[image: Unable to find a valid update server]

According to [a previous thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/187029/tex-live-utility-unable-to-find-update-server), the solution is to wait it out until the server is brought back up. However, I've been seeing this message for over a week now, so I suspect there maybe something else amiss.

---

macOS High Sierra 10.13.5

Comment: Which TeX Live version are you using? Anything below 2018? Then you'd definitely match the "version on the server does not match" part of the message.

Comment: @TeXnician: As mentioned in the opening sentence, I'm using version 1.34.

Comment: It's not about the version of TeX Live Utility, but which TeX Live version do you have? TL17, TL18 or something different?

Comment: TeX Live utility is a tool build on top of MacTeX, since only Mac users have this tool it is much more important to us to know the version of MacTeX

Comment: @daleif: How can I find out?

Comment: Run pdfLaTeX from the Terminal and there's usually a header that outputs the distro version.

Comment: @TeXnician: Thanks. It appears I run TeX Live 2017. But it has worked fine so far; I've used TeX Live Utility several times in 2018. Oh, well.

Comment: But most mirrors have (at least since may) TL18 instead of TL17 as main release, so for further updates you need to install TL18 (or MacTeX 18).

Comment: You might want to send an email to the people maintaining the TL Utility and ask them to phrase that message in a way normal people can understand.

Comment: @TeXnician : TeX Live 2018/MacTeX-2018 was released in May of 2018 so you may have previously updated TeX Live 2017 in 2018.

Comment: @HerbSchulz That's basically what I wrote (maybe the "at least" was a little bit misplaced as the majority of mirrors haven't been pretest mirrors).